# Is there a tool to automatically generate code to preload images based on usage in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, image, preload

I have a relatively large Javascript web application that contains a number of images, references from either HTML or CSS (but not dynamically from Javascript). Is there a tool that scans all my CSS and HTML files, collects the URL:s of all detected images and generates the code required to preload all of them so I can launch the application only when everything has been downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can launch your application in body's onload handler? It should be fired when everything is fetched, and you'll then not need to iterate over all elements.

Comment: This will not cover the case of images referenced in CSS that have not yet become visible, I need something that ensures that when parts of the application are displayed I do not get flicker due to not yet available images.

Comment: Ouch, that would indeed be a problem. I wonder in what situations will onload be called before loading images: for display:none elements? for visibility:hidden elements? Or are there just definitions in the CSS which are not used at all in the document, and obviously for them the content will not be fetched...?

Comment: I think body onload doesn't even wait for the images in HTML part. As far as I'm concerned it fires when the DOM is loaded, it doesn't care for the images. I'm afraid you can't do that automatically from JS. You could try writing your own preloader that loads all the necessary images and start the application once it’s job is done. But then you would have get rid of all the image references in the HTML and CSS and assign them via JS or else you would have every image requested for twice...

Comment: @Michal, what I am looking for is a tool to process all my HTML and CSS and generate the code to preload them in a monitored way. This should not require changing the HTML and CSS as, once preloaded, they would be served from the cache.